# combining alpha over nodes

Tags: transparency, masking

I have two masks of different parts of a picture.  In each mask I want to completely replace the colors in the mask...a different color for each mask. Should I be trying to do it in the compositor like this, and if so what is the node I am missing?  Or is there a better way for this noob?  Thank you so much.
[image: combining alpha channels]

Comment: Another "Alpha Over"

Answer (score 1):

ok here is one way is figured out how to get my result!
[image: adding two mask]